# String variable as href in lxml.builder

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, lxml, literals

I am building HTML table from the list through **lxml.builder** and striving to make a link in one of the table cells

List is generated in a following way:

```
with open('some_file.html', 'r') as f:
     table = etree.parse(f)
p_list = list()
rows = table.iter('div')
p_list.append([c.text for c in rows])
rows = table.xpath("body/table")[0].findall("tr")
for row in rows[2:]:
    p_list.append([c.text for c in row.getchildren()])
```

HTML file which I parse is **the same** that is generated further by lxml, i.e. I set up some sort of recursion for testing purposes.

And here is how I build table

```
from lxml.builder import E

page = (
E.html(
    E.head(
    E.title("title")
    ),
    E.body(
 ....

*[E.tr(
 *[
      E.td(E.a(E.img(src=str(col)))) if ind == 8 else
      E.td(E.a(str(col), href=str(col))) if ind == 9 else
      E.td(str(col)) for ind, col in enumerate(row)
  ]
) for row in p_list ]
```

When I specify link via literals all is going fine.

```
E.td(E.a("link", href="url_address"))
```

However, when I try to output list element value (which is `https://blahblahblah.com`) as a link

```
E.td(E.a(str(col), href=str(col)))
```

cell is empty, just nothing is showed in the cell.

If I specify link text as a literal and put `str (col)` into href, the link is showed normally, but instead of real href it contains the **name of the generated html file**.

If I output just that `col` value as a string

```
E.td(str(col))
```

it is showed normally, i.e. **it is not empty**. What is wrong with `E.a` and `E.img` elements?

Just noticed that this happens only if I build list from html file. When I build list manually, like this, all is output fine.

```
p_list = []
p_element = ['id']
p_element.append('value')
p_element.append('value2')
p_list.append(p_element)
```

**Current output** (pay attention to `<a>` and `<href>` tags)

```
   <html>
   <head>
     <title>page</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <style type="text/css">
          th {
                 background-color: DeepSkyBlue;
                 text-align: center;
                 vertical-align: bottom;
                 height: 150px;
                 padding-bottom: 3px;
                 padding-left: 5px;
                 padding-right: 5px;
         }
         .vertical {
                 text-align: center;
                 vertical-align: middle;
                 width: 20px;
                 margin: 0px;
                 padding: 0px;
                 padding-left: 3px;
                 padding-right: 3px;
                 padding-top: 10px;
                 white-space: nowrap;
                 -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
                 -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);              
          }</style>
     <h1>title</h1>
     <p>This is another paragraph, with a</p>
     <table border="2">
       <tr>
         <th>
           <div class="vertical">ID</div>
         </th>
        ...
         <th>
           <div class="vertical">I blacklisted him</div>
         </th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>1020</td>
         <td>&#1058;&#1072;&#1080;&#1089;&#1080;&#1103;&#1057;&#1090;&#1088;&#1072;&#1093;&#1086;&#1083;&#1077;&#1090;</td>
         <td>No</td>
         <td>Female</td>
         <td>None</td>
         <td>&#1057;&#1072;&#1085;&#1082;&#1090;-&#1055;&#1077;&#1090;&#1077;&#1088;&#1073;&#1091;&#1088;&#1075;</td>
         <td>&#1056;&#1086;&#1089;i&#1103;</td>
         <td>None</td>
         <td>
           <a>
             <img src="&#10;          "/>
           </a>
         </td>
         <td>
           <a href="&#10;          ">
           </a>
         </td>
        ...
       </tr>
     </table>
   </body>
 </html>
```

**Desired output**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <style type="text/css">
         th {
                background-color: DeepSkyBlue;
                text-align: center;
                vertical-align: bottom;
                height: 150px;
                padding-bottom: 3px;
                padding-left: 5px;
                padding-right: 5px;
        }
        .vertical {
                text-align: center;
                vertical-align: middle;
                width: 20px;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
                padding-left: 3px;
                padding-right: 3px;
                padding-top: 10px;
                white-space: nowrap;
                -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
                -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);              
         }</style>
    <h1>title</h1>
    <p>This is another paragraph, with a</p>
    <table border="2">
      <tr>
        <th>
          <div class="vertical">ID</div>
        </th>
        ...
        <th>
          <div class="vertical">I blacklisted him</div>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1019</td>
        <td>&#1052;&#1080;&#1093;&#1072;&#1080;&#1083;&#1055;&#1072;&#1074;&#1083;&#1086;&#1074;</td>
        <td>No</td>
        <td>Male</td>
        <td>None</td>
        <td>&#1057;&#1072;&#1085;&#1082;&#1090;-&#1055;&#1077;&#1090;&#1077;&#1088;&#1073;&#1091;&#1088;&#1075;</td>
        <td>&#1056;&#1086;&#1089;i&#1103;</td>
        <td>C.-&#1055;&#1077;&#1090;&#1077;&#1088;&#1073;&#1091;&#1088;&#1075;</td>
        <td>
          <a>
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/rejChZW.jpg"/>
          </a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="http://i.imgur.com/rejChZW.jpg">link</a>
        </td>
        ...
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @mzjn, added list forming code

Comment: It's `p_list`. Corrected the vars

Comment: @ pure HTML. Generated exactly with the same ElementTree builder.

Comment: I set up recursion for testing purposes: I generate HTML and then parse it again.

Comment: Added the HTML sample. I exposed all my code. Cannot add nothing more

Comment: please Minimal example,add the output and the desire output.

Comment: @obgnaw, added outputs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got it myself. The problem was not in generating but in parsing HTML. Parsing function didn't fetch `IMG` and `A` tags nested in `TD` and these elements of the list were empty. Due to the rigorous logic of the program (fetching from file + fetching from site API) I wasn't able to detect the cause of the issue.

The correct parsing logic should be:

```
for row in rows[1:]:
    data.append([
                 c.find("a").text if c.find("a") is not None else
                 c.find("img").attrib['src'] if c.find("img") is not None else
                 c.text
                 for c in row.getchildren()
                ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but it looks like 'str()' could be escaping it.  Try E.td(E.a(col, href=col))

Comment: Was the result the same?  It looks like 'col' may be an object rather than string.  Are you able to print the value from col outside the link?

Comment: Yes, it is string: if I print(`type(element)`) throughout the list, it prints `<class 'str'>`. And yes, result is the same.

Comment: It seems more a parse problem, than output problem. When I print the list after parsing, it prints all the elements fine **except** 8th and 9th element: they are empty.